# Use of unresolved identifier 'segue'

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, ios11, xcode9

I'm trying to export my data from a ViewController to another with this code:

```
   func prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
   let desty : EndViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! EndViewController 
   desty.totalScore = scoreTotal.text!
   }
```

But when I try to do that is turns me the error:
[Use of unresolved identifier 'segue']
But I've already done it as you can see here:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu1Sm.png)
So how can I solve it.
I will be so grateful if you help me.
Please, help a young programmer to learn.

Comment: You've got the method signature wrong, you don't have a parameter names `segue`. Maybe you intended to implement `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

Comment: @johan so how should I change it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong function. It should be...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, perform your segues as below:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueID", sender: self)
```

Now, call prepareForSegue and change the values in destination accordingly:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourSegueID" {
        let vc = segue.destination
        vc.yourVariable = "Some Value"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to correct it like this: 

          func prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
          self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
          if segue.identifier == "segue" {
            let vc : EndViewController = segue.destinationViewController
                vc.totalScore = scoreTotal.text!}
        }
But it turns me back the same errors

Comment: Its an override method. Did you insert the override keyword?
The method definition must be of format override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)

Comment: Please follow my previous comment.

Comment: override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)

Answer (score 0):

The internal parameter label `segue` is missing in the first parameter and the type of the second parameter is wrong.

**Please use code completion**

- Comment out your entire method

  ```
  // func prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
  //   let desty : EndViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! EndViewController 
  //   desty.totalScore = scoreTotal.text!
  //   }
  ```
- Type <kbd>prep</kbd>, you will see

[image]

- Choose the proper line and press <kbd>return</kbd>.
- Copy the body of the former method into the new one.